# Replace blank with another column value in SSIS derived column Transformation

Tags: ssis

I need to replace the blank value with the column Data2
Original Table

```
            +-------+--------+
            | data1 | Data2  |
            +-------+--------+
            | 45789 |  45789 |
            | 56897 |  56897 |
            |       |  56897 |
            | 56485 |  56485 |
            |       | 897458 |
            +-------+--------+
```

Expected Table

```
            +-------+--------+
            | data1 | Data2  |
            +-------+--------+
            | 45789 |  45789 |
            | 56897 |  56897 |
            | 56897 |  56897 |
            | 56485 |  56485 |
            | 897458| 897458 |
            +-------+--------+
```

I tried this not working

```
 data1 == "" ? data1 : data2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is true if two columns have the same data type. If data types are different, you need to cast the data2 column.

[image]

Enable data viewer to check your result, It works properly:

[image]

You can also use another way. Write a TSQL query to replace the Data1 column with Data2 Column

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN Data1 = '' THEN Data2 ELSE Data1 END  Data1
      ,Data2
FROM YourTable
```